# Flipboard briefing app news item animation on android

Tags: android-activity, android-animation

On recent samsung devices, when I open Flipboard briefing app and click on some news item, The news loads an animation where-in it breaks from middle and expands up and down to reveal the full news article. 
I want to implement same animation in my application. I tried searching for any pointer to this, but couldn't find any.

I have gone through flipboard animation library

http://openaphid.github.io/blog/2012/05/21/how-to-implement-flipboard-animation-on-android/

but it explains the old animation. I also worked on the FoldableLayout library available on github at

https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/109

but it just hide/unhides the data between animations.

Can anyone help me explain the method used by the flipboard briefing app.

regards,

Rajan